# Indexing error implementing geofire in cloud function

Tags: google-cloud-functions, geofire

I am geolocating jobs and users in my application. I am creating 2 global indexes in my index.js as follows:

```
const geousers = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref().child('geolocation').child('users'));
const geojobs = new GeoFire(admin.database().ref().child('geolocation'.child('jobs')));
```

I do a geoQuery in my function:

```
exports.nearbyjobs = functions.database.ref("/users/{userid}/account/l").onWrite((event) => {
  const location = event.data;
  if (location.child("lat").val() === null || location.child("lng").val() === null) return false;
  const uid = event.params.userid;
  let lat = Number(location.child("lat").val());
  let lng = Number(location.child("lng").val());
  const geoQuery = geojobs.query({
    center: [lat, lng],
    radius: 0.7
  });
  return admin.database().ref(`users/${uid}/nearbyjobs`).remove().then(data => {
    geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
      return Promise.all([admin.database().ref(`jobs/${key}/category`).once('value'), admin.database().ref(`users/${uid}/account/categories`).once('value')]).then(r => {
        const promises = [];
        const cP = r[0];
        const cO = r[1];
        if (cO.val().includes(cP.val())){
          return admin.database().ref(`users/${uid}/nearbyjobs/${key}`).set({
            jobkey: key,
            distance: distance,
            l: location
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

In my functions console I am getting the warning:

> FIREBASE WARNING: Using an unspecified index. Your data will be
>   downloaded and filtered on the client. Consider adding ".indexOn": "g"
>   at /geojobs to your security rules for better performance.

Database structure for geolocation:

```
geolocation
   |
   -users
     |
      +<key>
   |
   -jobs
     |
      +<key>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, are you sure that the document name of your database is job? According to the error, I guess you have created a document store as geojobs.
Anyways, this is how you solve the above error, assuming your document store name is geojobs
You have to add a rule to under geojobs. Go to Firebase console --> Database --> Rules.

You will see something like the below,

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```

You will have to change it to following by adding `.indexOn`.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "geojobs": {
      ".indexOn": ["g"]
    }
  }
}
```